# GetThumbnail from video?

Tags: filemaker

I've successfully created thumbnails from pictures stored in containers but have not got it to work when the source container contains a video.

When I use import from folder, and the folder contains videos FM does it automatically so I expect I'm missing something.

I'm using Set Field with this calculation;

```
GetThumbnail ( videoField ;
    GetWidth ( videoField ) / 2 ; 
    GetHeight (videoField ) / 2 )
```

Comment: Have you tried using a fixed width and height instead of the GetWidth and GetHeight properties? GetThumbnail ( videoField ; 500 ; 500 )

Comment: Yes I have, still doesn't work.